# cifar100 pytorch download root

Tags: pytorch

```
train_data=torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='',....,download=True)
```

When I download CIFAR100 datasets and select the root,are the dataset downloaded in the root that I selected?
I cannot find any file or images.
How can I see the file?

Answer (score 0):

The `root` argument your pass to `torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100` is relative to your current working directory. It will download the data there:

```
>>> torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root='.', download=True)
```

In the current directory (since `root='.'`), you will find the `.tar.gz` and uncompressed directory `cifar-100-python/`, containing the dataset:

```
>>> ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000      4096 Feb 20  2010 cifar-100-python/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 169001437 Jan 21 16:02 cifar-100-python.tar.gz
```